# Select distinct DataTable rows

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` where sometimes values in all columns in two or more rows repeat. I would like to get distinct DataTable. The solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199176/how-to-select-distinct-rows-in-a-datatable-and-store-into-an-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466253/select-distinct-values-from-a-large-datatable-column/17466380) don't work for me because I have many columns and depending on some conditions, the number of columns changes.

I was thinking maybe something like this

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable(); // already fulfilled table

DataView view = new DataView(table);
var tableDistinct = view.ToTable(true, table.Columns);
```

But I can't pass `table.Columns` as an argument.

Comment: _"but it does't work"_ More informations please

Comment: I guess in your case its the backend sql query which need to be modified rather the dataview. So, use distinct in your sql query and see if your getting distinct rows.

Comment: I can't edit sql query because during creating datatable I make conditions/ change names in rows so that at the end I am receiving duplicated rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToTable access a list of string params, the following should convert all your columns to array of string so you don't have to enter them manually

```
 System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable(); // already fulfilled table

            DataView view = new DataView(table);
            var tableDistinct = view.ToTable(true, table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(z=>z.ColumnName).ToArray());
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but I also noticed that without passing this second parameter, only  `table = view.ToTable(true);` still works. Do you think I could leave  the code this way, or it is better to give second parameter?

Comment: Really, not sure about that to be honest

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what's going wrong because you haven't said what's not working. However, you could use LINQ(-TO-DataTable):

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new{ Col1 = r["Col1"], Col2 = r["Col2"], Col3 = r["Col3"] })
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Change the columns in the anonymous type according to your column-list.

Comment: For your answer or for the original question?